# Fatal Error Cannot redeclare name() Joomla

Tags: php, javascript

tengo el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare name() (previously declared in C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\php\prueba.php:8) in C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\php\prueba.php on line 8

y mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
name();

function name() {
  echo 'Hola';  
};

/*
echo "<script>
name();
function name() {
alert('hola mundo');
}
</script>";
*/
?>
```

Como pueden es básico esto solo es el llamado de la funcion y ejecutar, ahora como pueden observar hay un codigo en JS en donde si se ejecuta la funcion.

He visto el error log de PHP el cual arroja lo siguiente:

`[03-Feb-2019 22:58:55 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[03-Feb-2019 22:58:55 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\index.php:0
[03-Feb-2019 22:58:55 UTC] PHP   2. Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->execute() C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\index.php:49
[03-Feb-2019 22:58:55 UTC] PHP   3. Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->render() C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\libraries\src\Application\CMSApplication.php:202
[03-Feb-2019 22:58:55 UTC] PHP   4. Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->render() C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\libraries\src\Application\SiteApplication.php:778
[03-Feb-2019 22:58:55 UTC] PHP   5. Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->triggerEvent() C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\libraries\src\Application\CMSApplication.php:1049
[03-Feb-2019 22:58:55 UTC] PHP   6. JEventDispatcher->trigger() C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\libraries\src\Application\BaseApplication.php:108
[03-Feb-2019 22:58:55 UTC] PHP   7. plgSystemJumi->update() C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\libraries\joomla\event\dispatcher.php:160
[03-Feb-2019 22:58:55 UTC] PHP   8. plgSystemJumi->onAfterRender() C:\wamp64\www\visitantes\libraries\joomla\event\event.php:70`

Alguien sabe que pasa aqui.

Estoy usando wamp server 3.1.7
php 7.3.1
apache 2.4.37
Joomla 3.9.2

Comment: El debug te esta indicando que el metodo `name` ya esta declarado en otro archivo, simplemente cambia el nombre del metodo y listo!

Comment: Hola @IvanIsayenko ya he cambiado el nombre del metodo, por otros tantos, y sigue marcando error.

Comment: La verdad es que no hay errores de syntaxis, podrias enseñar el archivo prueba.php?